# Why does the impedance of a parallel RLC circuit approach infinity at resonance?

Tags: passive-networks, basic

Pretty new to this stuff so apologies if I get some words wrong.

In the book I'm reading they described a parallel circuit with a resistor capacitor and an inductor powered by a current source. They say the capacitor has impedance \$\frac{1}{j\omega C}\$  and the inductor has impedance \$j\omega L\$ and the resistor has resistance \$R_{p}\$. The resonant frequency is when the magnitudes of the two impedances of the capacitor and the inductor are equal i.e. \$\omega_0^2 = \frac{1}{LC}\$. But when I use the parallel resistance formula I get the impedance of the circuit should be

$$\left(\frac{1}{R}_p + j\omega C + \frac{1}{j\omega L}\right)^{-1}$$

But  at resonant frequency where \$\omega C = \frac{1}{\omega L}\$ this comes out to \$R_{p}\$, not infinity. So I'm struggling to understand what they're trying to say here.

To clarify some things here's the page from the book I'm reading. (Electronics with Digital and Analog Integrated Circuits by Higgins)

[image]

Comment: No @mkeith, the book is correct, parallel R with a current source has  2 dimensional impedance

Comment: Where precisely does the book say this erroneous thing? Copy and paste please, verbatim.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 what do you mean by a "2 dimensional impedance"?

Comment: We would need to see the schematic they are referring to here. Assuming Rp, L and C are all in parallel, then the only basis for saying Z "approaches infinity" is that Rp is typically chosen as a very high value (itself approaching infinity) and that at resonance, Z=Rp. Otherwise the book is at best sloppy.

Comment: @mkeith if they meant L and C in parallel, and R in series with LC, then the formula for Q is wrong.

Comment: @Andyaka  R+jX as a 2D  orthogonal impedance at resonance is all about X(fo)=0 regardless of R with Q as the ratio

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy wrong assumption the book is correct and current source is used in shunt not series unless you want to rewrite the book for a current source with a series R

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 I said nothing about current source vs voltage source. I said that _if_ they meant LC in parallel and R in series with LC, then the formula for Q would be wrong. What is hard to understand about that?

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 I did not suggest R should be in series. I stated that _if_ R was in series, as mkeith had suggested, then the formula for Q would be wrong. I was arguing directly _against_ the idea that R was in series.

Comment: Sorry, of course @mkeith you started this misunderstanding and the error that the Op “appears to be correct” pls delete your comments and inititial misleading statement

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 I deleted my comment but I am not really following so...

Answer (score 1):

What book? Do they actually say the impedance of the RLC circuit approaches infinity or just that the impedance of the LC section approaches infinity.  Your calculation is correct but you may be misinterpreting the book.

Comment: That's what I was thinking but I'm trying to figure out what they were really saying. They just have a table (i now posted) that says "Impedance at resonance: Approaches Infinity" but they don't really say much to explain that result.

Comment: Onye , if you insert for **increasing Q or for getting closer to resonance** , it will make more sense to you, but the book is 100% correct.. Going to 10 to 100 is going towards infinity ohms in // and towards 0 in series

Comment: This is the correct thinking. Some users are misinterpreting the book.

Answer (score 0):

R acts a damping factor to parallel LC and determines the bandwidth, BW, and risetime and R/Zc(fo)=Q=fo/BW

Thus if R were ideally infinite ! Q is infinite and any fo oscillation remains constant forever with Zc(fo)=-ZL(fo) in the complex (reactive) domain, and \$f_o 2\pi=\omega_o\$

Comment: This diode has leakage R so it is pumped for 10ns every cycle to build up the sine wave at almost the resonant frequency, but very close.  pull the diode off and it goes forever https://tinyurl.com/yy4tyvjf

Comment: Thanks for the input. I'm not sure if I understand everything you've said but I'll think more about it.

Comment: The Book is 100% correct

Comment: look at my simulation pul the gen , R or diode from the circuit. what happens? https://tinyurl.com/yyw7zz6z

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, and the book appears to be wrong. In a parallel RLC circuit, when the driving frequency is the resonant frequency, the impedance is the resistance of R, not \$\infty\$. In a pure LC circuit, with ideal components, the impedance approaches \$\infty\$.

The impedance at any frequency is
$$Z= R || X_C || X_L$$

(where \$X_C\$ and \$X_L\$ have imaginary values.)

At resonance (and assuming ideal components)

$$X_C = -X_L$$

so

$$Z_0 = R || X_C ||( -X_C) = \frac{\displaystyle 1}{\displaystyle \frac{\displaystyle 1}{\displaystyle R}+\frac{\displaystyle 1}{\displaystyle X_C} + \frac{\displaystyle 1}{\displaystyle -X_C}} = R$$

If instead, X_L and X_C are given a *real*, positive values, the formulas become

$$X_C = X_L$$

and

$$Z_0 = R || (jX_C) ||( -jX_C) = \frac{\displaystyle 1}{\displaystyle \frac{\displaystyle 1}{\displaystyle R}+\frac{\displaystyle 1}{\displaystyle jX_C} + \frac{\displaystyle 1}{\displaystyle -jX_C}} = R$$

Both ways of solving for \$Z_0\$ obviously give the same answer,

$$Z_0=R$$.

For clarity, what I assume to be a parallel RLC circuit looks like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fW5OBV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: This is incorrect.  The impedance is 2 dimensional not 1. The book  may confuse some , but it is correct

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75. You are correct that Impedance is _complex_ (2 dimensional) but you are mistaken that the impedance of a parallel RLC circuit at resonance is not R. The impedance at resonance is R. I have added the math to my answer.

Comment: The Impedance of X(f)= 0 . I ignored R as it is irrelevant to LC resonance if Q>1. I am not wrong, The book is not wrong. This answer is wrong in the initial assumption. It's just a silly misunderstanding. And this is like explaining how to add 1+1 to me.. which is 0. Proof XOR gate

Comment: And what exactly is "the initial assumption" you speak of?

Comment: Your opening statement “the book is wrong”

Comment: That is not an assumption, it is a conclusion, and it is a conclusion based upon calculating the impedance of a parallel RLC circuit using established formulae.

Comment: Yes you have the write circuit diagram. I apologize for not posting it earlier.